# How to dispatch a method call to several handlers automatically in Python

Tags: python

Here is my situation:

I have a class like this:

```
class Handler:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def gogo(self, input):
        print("My name is %s and I got %s" % (self.name, input))
```

What I would want to achieve is something like this:

```
dispatcher = Dispatcher(Handler("who"), Handler("what"))
dispatcher.gogo("food")

>> "My name is who and I got food"
>> "My name is what and I got food"
```

My first attempts at this was to create a Dispatcher class that creates its own method in its `__init__` method. In that case, every method of Dispatcher would just trigger the same methods on the different handlers. The downside is that it won't work if any new method is added to the handlers **after** the dispatcher is initialized.

So my second attempt is to have a `__getattr__` method that generates a new method calling the handler methods every time it is called, so basically like this:

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    methods = []
    for destination in self._destinations:
        if hasattr(destination, item):
            destination_method = getattr(destination, item)

            # if the argument is not callable, we are not interested, we cannot do anything with it
            # Maybe we should even raise an error here?
            if callable(destination_method):
                methods.append(destination_method)

    # If none of the destinations had a method for this name, we cannot do anything and should raise
    if len(methods) == 0:
        raise NotImplementedError("No method found for property %s" % item)

    # Create a wrapper around the methods that we detected that will just pass the arguments
    def new_method(*args, **kwargs):
        for method in methods:
            method(*args, **kwargs)

    return new_method
```

The downside of this one is that it generates a new method every time, which is not super nice in general. In addition, it just doesn't feel that nice and may be prone to errors (for instance the dispatcher is pretty opaque, and when you get it you cannot be sure of what methods are available or not).

The number of methods that I want to implement is known, so in theory I can have a base class for all the handlers that would contain every method **potentially** implemented by them.

I am looking for a solution that would be as elegant as possible that does not involve a big overhead in `dispatcher.gogo("food")` as it is supposed to be a really straightforward system.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just move the dispatcher method from the local scope to the instance level?

```
class Dispatcher():

    def __dispatch(self, *args , **kwargs):
        for method in self.__methods:
            method(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        self.__methods = []
        …
                if callable(destination_method):
                    self.__methods.append(destination_method)
        …
        return self.__dispatch
```